# Add all duplicate values in mysqli

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I have an tabel `trade` as following:-

```
 bm | m | price | amount | status
 USD|BTC| 0.01  | 1      | active
 USD|BTC| 0.01  | 2.5    | active
 USD|BTC| 0.4   | 0.5    | active
 USD|BTC| 0.4   | 0.22   | active
```

I want to add amounts of duplicate price i.e 0.01 and 0.4 where status is active and show them so that the result is like:-

```
 price | amount
 0.01  | 3.5
 0.4   | 0.722
```

I have tried an php query for showing but it shows values and rows as it is. Help please.

Comment: GROUP BY and SUM()!

Comment: I don't know much of mysqli, can explain?

Answer (score 1):

Simply do a `GROUP BY`, use `SUM()` to calculate the sum for each price!

```
select price, sum(amount)
from tablename
WHERE bm = 'usd' and m = 'btc' 
group by price
```

Comment: Also i need the statement WHERE bm = 'usd' and m = 'btc'

Comment: Now with your WHERE added!

Comment: Perhaps you want to add `AND status = 'active'` to the WHERE clause?

Comment: But how do i get these values in php

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know php.

Comment: @JeffB In your question you said that you tried to run a `php` query which showed all the results. Well, run the query provided by @jarlh instead of yours and I guess you'll see the correct results.

Comment: But what about mysqli_fetch_array?

Comment: Nvm i found the solution.